# strtol differs in debug and release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I use following code in c++ compiling with visual studio 2008:

```
char input = 'K';
long output= strtol(&input , NULL, 36);
```

In debug mode it works fine, the output is 20.
But in release mode it makes strange outputs, like 604663109.
It also works, when I set disable code optimization, but that can't be the solution.
I also know, how to calculate it by hand, but I want to know, why there is a difference between debug and release mode?

EDITED: Sorry, it has to be char and not char*. But same error.

Comment: Does removing the address-of operator make difference? I would also suggest to declare input as const char*

Comment: Sorry, it has to be char and not char*. But same error.

Comment: With GCC, your original code: "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char\*’" and "error: cannot convert ‘char\*\*’ to ‘const char\*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘long int strtol(const char*, char\*\*, int)’". Your new code after edit: "error: invalid conversion from ‘const char\*’ to ‘char’". Can you post the truly really _actual code_ please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtoul doesn't work on char, only on null terminated strings. You'll have to use a null terminated string, or find another way. E.g.

```
char input = 'K';
...
char temp[2] = { input, '\0' };
long output = strtol(temp, NULL, 36);
```

Comment: Wow, now it works. Thanks very much. But why did it work in debug mode?

Comment: Because you didn't have a null terminated string. This is an example of *undefined behaviour* (UB), and it's common for programs with UB to *seem* to work, even though they are really bugged. It's one of the things that makes C++ hard.

Comment: @SpeziFish most likely the debugger zeroed the bytes in memory after your char, in release they had some different value (whatever was there before). But as stated by john, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Since `&input` doesn't point to a null-terminated character array, the code has undefined behaviour.

This should work:

```
const char* input = "K";
long output = strtol(input , NULL, 36);
```

The reason it *appears* to work in the debug build is probably that the compiler has inserted "magic" values around the `input` variable in order to enable detection of stack corruption, and a zero happens to be placed at `&input + 1`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But can't change the type of 'input', so john's solution is the better one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your call is wrong, you shouldn't take the address of the pointer!

It should be:

```
strtoul(input, NULL, 36);
```